# Scheduled jobs run forever in Zeppelin, stop interpreter option disappears on its own

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cron, apache-zeppelin

I have an installation of Apache Zeppelin and Spark, where I run several notebooks. I have enabled cron scheduling option in the configuration:

- Set property zeppelin.notebook.cron.enable to true in $ZEPPELIN_HOME/conf/zeppelin-site.xml
- zeppelin.notebook.cron.folders is set to /

However, when I try to schedule some jobs (%pyspark or %livy.pyspark), usually they run forever:

[image]

(the same notebooks usually take from 5 minutes to 4 hours if run manually)

When I set the option "After execution stop the interpreter", as in the [Zeppelin manual](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/usage/other_features/cron_scheduler.html#setting-up-a-cron-scheduler-on-a-notebook), and kept the browser window with notebooks opened, it worked for the first time:

[image]

However, afterwards, the tick in that option disappeared on its own. And some more days later, the whole option disappeared completely:

[image]

Do you have an idea, how to make scheduled jobs in Zeppelin working properly? I do not like to run notebooks via API because of configured authentication.

Comment: Which version of zeppelin do you use

Comment: My Zeppelin version is 0.9.0, spark 2.4.7, livy 0.7.1 (the problem exists both with livy and without it)